# How to return files in powershell with the same extension, but containing a specific end to the name?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

There are multiple .webp files in a project folder. Some .webps are the original picture and some function as thumbnail (their size is different). The used naming convention is: original files are just called NAME.webp and tumbnails are NAME-thumb.webp. I am trying to create a Powershell script that returns all the -thumb.webp files based on the original files creation date. So, if the original files was created today, return the corresponding -thumb.webp (they have the same basename apart from the -thumb

This is what I tried so far, but something is still off:

```
$webps = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.webp' -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $refdate }).BaseName
$output = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.webp' -File | Where-Object { $webps -contains ($_.BaseName + "-thumb") }
```

Comment: Is there always a corresponding "NAME-thumb.webp" for each "NAME.webp"?

Comment: Yes there always is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem $dir\*.webp -Exclude *-thumb.webp -File | 
    Where-Object CreationTime -gt $refdate | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Fullname -replace '\.webp$', '-thumb.webp' }
```

First we get all **.webp* files, excluding **-thumb.webp* files. Using `Where-Object` we select only files whose `CreationTime` is greater than `$refdate`. Finally we replace *.webp* by *-thumb.webp* to return the full paths of the thumbnail files.

If you only need the filenames, replace `$_.Fullname` by `$_.Name`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) can help:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).Date # today's calendar day, for instance.

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $dir -Filter *.webp |
  Group-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '-thumb$' } | # by base name without suffix
    ForEach-Object {
      # Test the creation date of the non-thumbnail *.webp file,
      # which comes alphabetically first in the group.
      if ($_.Group[0].CreationTime -gt $refDate) {
        $_.Group[1] # Output the corresponding *-thumb.webp file
      }
    }
```

- `-replace '-thumb$'` uses the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to remove the `-thumb` suffix from the file base names, so that `<name>.webp` and `<name>-thumb.webp` files with the same `<name>` are grouped together.
- The above assumes that every `<name>.webp` file has a `<name>-thumb.webp` counterpart, in which case each `$_.Group` array contains two [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances, with the first always representing the `<name>.webp`, and the second the `<name>-thumb.webp` file, because `Compare-Object` sorts the group members by the grouping criterion/a.